# How to make dropdown list with checkboxes using Spring MVC?

Tags: html, spring, checkbox

I need to do something like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHyyx.png, but how can I do this with spring's tags? May I input into `form:select` or `form:option` a checkbox?

Comment: see if this helps, http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5649/

Comment: thanks, ul-li good, but no way to do this using spring's tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this if we use `JSTL` and create `html` required for it. Use `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css`. We can download them and add in our spring project from internet.

Example is here.

[image: Checkbox dropdown]

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

//import bootstrap js and css
<script  src="../js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link href="../themes/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

//your form goes here

<form id="searchform" method="get" action="">
        <div align="center">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Select
                        Designation :</button>
                    <button tabindex="-1" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <li style="vertical-align: top;"> <input id="all" name="all" type="checkbox" style="width:30px;height:auto;cursor: pointer;"><label
                                style="vertical-align: middle;width:100%;cursor: pointer;;" for="all" > All</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <c:forEach items="${designationList}" var="d" varStatus="status">

                            <li style="vertical-align: top;"><input id="${d.id}" name="${d.id}" type="checkbox" style="width:30px;height:auto;cursor: pointer;"> <label
                             for="${d.id}"  class="lbl" style="color: #489D1F;vertical-align: middle;width:100%;cursor: pointer;"> ${d.designation}</label>
                            </li>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </div>

        </div>
    </form>
```

**Disclaimer :** *I do not know if the same is possible using Spring tags or not, but I just know this way so I shared it with you. May be someone may know and will post better answer. But this way may help you until we have proper way for spring tags.*